# Why download a csv generated by PHP with Ajax add a 0 to the end of the file?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, download

This is my code.

CSV generated from php:

```
function ajax_export() {
 $strFile = "Test";
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
 header("Cache-Control: private", false);
 // nothing changes: header('Content-Type: application/download; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"stats.csv\"");
 // not working: header("Content-length: ".strlen($strFile));   
 echo $strFile;
 return;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", '#download', function(event) {
var data = {};
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl, //load previous php function
    method: 'POST',
    // nothing changes dataType: 'text',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var form = $('<form method="POST" action="' + ajaxurl + '">');
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="' + k + '" value="' + v + '">'));
        });
        $('body').append(form);
        form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

This code works, a csv is send to client to downloading.
But in PHP, the string is "Test", instead in console or in downloaded csv, the output is "Test0".
Where does this zero come from and how can it be eliminated?

Comment: Try using `return $strFile;` as it may be that somewhere you are echoing the result of this function.

Comment: Would be USEFUL to see the code that CALLS this function

Comment: @NigelRen I already tried. I tried also return '' and no return at all, nothing changes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code is all here; I'm inside wordpress, and there is a add_action('wp_ajax_exportstats', 'ajax_export' );
Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself.
In php, instead of return; conclude function with die().
Like this:

```
function ajax_export() {
 $strFile = "Test";
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
 header("Cache-Control: private", false);
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"stats.csv\"");
 echo $strFile;
 die();
}
```